# 'import pyPDF2' results in 'ModuleNotFoundError'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pypdf, modulenotfounderror

Summary of problem:
Using the python interpreter, I type `import pyPDF2` and get a ModuleNotFound error even though I have installed the pyPDF2 module:

```py
>>> import pyPDF2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyPDF2'
```

What I have tried:
I am using Windows 10. I am new to python. I have installed Python 3.8.3 to a `C:\Python38` folder. I have installed `pyPDF2` via 'pip install pyPDF2'. The windows path includes the folders: `C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\`.

At the windows Command Prompt I type 'python' and get:

```
c:\>python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

At the python interpreter prompt I type 'import pyPDF2' and get:

```py
>>> import pyPDF2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyPDF2'
>>>
```

Note: There is installed an old version of python 2.7 from an ArcGIS install. Could that be causing a conflict? If not, I would rather not uninstall that version since it goes with ArcGIS, which I use.

What I am really trying to do is to automate the concatenation of 7,696 pdf files into 104 pdf files. So far my program looks like this:

```py
import os
from pyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

source_dir = os.getcwd()

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.beginswith('District001_Pg'):
        merger.append(item)

merger.write('District001.pdf')
merger.close()
```

Any help anyone is able to provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could check if pyPDF2 has been installed in your old python version by doing the same test than for the new python version : launch the interpreter, then type import pyPDF2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run 2 different versions of python in the same machine without having conflicts, you can use VirtualEnv. Here is a document which I found on the web to get you started.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-using-virtualenv/

Comment: I submitted this question.  I followed the suggestion of @justnisar and it worked great. My problem is resolved.  How do I close this post?